# Encrypt a query string inside of an anchor tag

Tags: php

```
echo '<a class="bigbtn" href="'.'videoview.php?song_id='.$video['song_id'].'&'.'title='.$video['VideoTITLE'].'&'.'group='.$video['GroupName'].'&'.'artist='.$video['ByArtist'].'"></a>' ;
```

what is the best way to encrypt the link when appear in the browser a that user cannot tamper with them?. it's not mission critical link. but want to make it a little more secure.

i was trying with the urlencode and decode with base64 , but i try to assign the value to a variable like that.

```
 $song_id = urldecode(base64_decode($_Get['song_id']));
```

but the conversion didnot happen.

,the decode didnot happen the way that i was thinking.

Comment: What are you looking to prevent someone from doing? Mass-download all your assets? Sharing the link?

Comment: not to be able to see the variable info that i'm passing along , but i fan make it more secure , i will .

Comment: `base64_encode()` and `base64_decode()` work reliably. It they don't do waht you expect then either you expect the wrong thing or the code you implemented does not work.

Comment: i'm not a php expert ,i'm in a learning phase , probably i implement it wrong . do you have any example base on what the code above how to implement it .

Answer (score 3):

Base64 is a way to represent binary data in an ASCII string format, it has nothing to do with encryption.

Assuming that the encryption/decryption is to happen server side:

Encrypt with: [mcrypt-encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php).
Then, decrypt with: [mcrypt-decrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php)

An implementation example:

```
<?php
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $key = "secret";
    $text = "Keep it secret, keep it safe";

    //encrypt
    $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);

    //decrypt
    $originaltext = mcrypt_decrypt (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key ,$crypttext ,  MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Obfuscating variables or id's almost never pays off: if you want to protect a resource, use [authorization](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html).

If you want to protect against scraping of massive download, use IP monitoring to watch for access/quota.

But plain query / url messing is a cheap solution that won't pay in the long term in my opinion.